# undefinded is not an object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio

Hello I'm facing with render error in my movie app during printing results for movie searching. Im working in React-Native 0.70.5. Here is some code for this activity
[image: error message]
`

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput,ScrollView } from "react-native";

const Search = () => {
   const apiurl="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=XXX"
   const [state,setState] = useState({
   s: "Enter a movie",
   results:[]
   });

   const search = () => {
    axios(apiurl + "&query="+ state.s).then(({ data }) => {
        let results = data.search;
        console.log(data);
        setState(prevState => {
            return{...prevState, results: results }
        })
    })
    }
  return (
         <View>
         <TextInput
            onChangeText={text => setState(prevState => {
            return {...prevState, s:text}
            })}
            onSubmitEditing={search}
            value={state.s}
         />
        <ScrollView>
            {state.results.map(result =>(
                <View key={result.id}>
                    <Text>{result.title}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  center: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

export default Search;
```

`

How to change the construction of this function to print movie titles corectly ?

Comment: is your `console.log(data)` showing an array ?

Comment: In your debugging, is this problem happening on the first render?  Or after a `search()` operation is performed?  Basically, is `console.log(data)` executing?  And, if so, what does it log to the console?

Comment: here is some responce for this : LOG  {"page": 1, "results": [{"adult": false, "backdrop_path": "/b0PlSFdDwbyK0cf5RxwDpaOJQvQ.jpg", "genre_ids": [Array], "id": 414906, "original_language": "en", "original_title": "The Batman", "overview": "In his second year of fi
ghting crime, Batman uncovers corruption in Gotham City that connects to his own family while facing a serial killer known as the Riddler.", "popularity": 260.037, "poster_path": "/74xTEgt7R36Fpooo50r9T25onhq.jpg", "release_date": "
2022-03-01", "title": "The Batman",

Comment: its happening when I enter value in my textinput

Comment: @v4d3rinho: If that's the data you're receiving then you are setting `state.results` to `undefined`.  When you do this: `let results = data.search;`, what do you expect `data.search` to be and why?  It looks like this is just a typo, you just used the wrong name for your data property.

Comment: so which name i should use ?

Comment: @v4d3rinho: Well, what is the property name on the `data` object that you want to use?  Have you looked at your `data` object?  Do you know what structure it has?  Do you know what values you want to use?

Comment: I want to show title which property is title or orginal_title which you can see higher. Im fetching data to get results stored in api

Comment: @v4d3rinho: If you *look at* your data, you'll see that there's a property called `results` which contains an array and is *probably* the data you want.  *The point here* is that ***you*** need to examine and understand *your data*, not just use random property names and hope for the best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

##### This is just an example and not the best way to do it.

You need a success flag, something like this:

```
const [success,setSuccess] = useState(false);

const search = () => {
    axios(apiurl + "&query="+ state.s).then(({ data }) => {
        let results = data.results;
        console.log(data);
        setState(prevState => {
            return{...prevState, results: results }
        })
        setSuccess(true);
    })
    }

       <ScrollView>
            {success && state.results.map(result =>(
                <View key={result.id}>
                    <Text>{result.title}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If `state.results` is `undefined` then this will also produce an error for the same reason.

Comment: It does't produce an error but values of titles is not show to screen

Comment: Change your code from let results = data.search -> let results = data.results

Comment: It also can't print the value of titles on screen

Comment: Please edit your post to the latest code you are currently using

Comment: Sorr when I paste the full of your solution it works corretly. Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but you can try this below ScrollView code...

```
<ScrollView>
            {state.results.length>0 && (state.results.map((result) =>(
                <View key={result.id}>
                    <Text>{result.title}</Text>
                </View>
   

)))}
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This will not work because an empty array resolves to true in javascript.

Comment: If `state.results` is `undefined` then this will also produce an error for the same reason.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @v4d3rinho what is the issue any errors..?

Comment: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'state.results.length')

Answer (score -1):

use optional chaining. Might be sometimes you don't get result.

```
<ScrollView>
        {state?.results?.map(result =>(
            <View key={result?.id}>
                <Text>{result?.title}</Text>
            </View>
        ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Let me know is it helpful or not

Comment: It solve the error but i dont get results on my screen

Comment: Are you getting data? i mean in the console which you have added in your search function? while searching

Comment: yes im getting data in my console

Comment: Try using useCallback
  const search = useCallback<(event: LayoutChangeEvent) => void>((event) => {
  //your code
  }, []);

Comment: it produce the syntax error: missing semicolon